# Aligning cells in table on arbitrary anchor

Tags: tables, alignment, nicematrix

I'd like to align cells horizontally on an arbitrary anchor (actually, it's the horizontal zero position of a `tikz` picture).

I've tried to understand Davis Carlisle's implementation of the `dcolumn` package but it left me with an empty stare of unreachable understanding.

As in the example below, the cell contents will have different widths.

**EDIT**. Precision after David's comment: the content of the nodes can be many things (from empty text to several letters), and different things on different lines. When text on one side is empty (or short), it should not take up any space.

**EDIT 2:** Follow-up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582656/102121).

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
    \tikz {\node[left]{aaa};\node[right]{a};\draw[->] (0,1)--(0,-1);}\\
\hline
    \tikz {\node[left]{bb};\node[right]{bbbb};\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,1);}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of improperly aligned cells]

(arrows should be aligned).

Comment: oh I'm hurt now, and I thought the code comments were a work of art in themselves:-)

Comment: if you want to align like `D{.}{.}{-1}` then  you centre the cells but make sure your tikz nodes are the same width left and right so you need to box and measure aaa and a and then specify the width of the two nodes is the larger of those. Then same again for bbb that way the arrow is always in the centre but if your data is always wider on one side that wastes space. If you want to align like `D{.}{.}{4.2}` then right align the column and specify the width of the right node to a fixed size say 3em, if the actual entry is bigger the arrow stays aligned but the text sticks into the next column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't worry David, it's my fault entirely, I could've put some more effort into it. But I generally use your packages with great pleasure, without needing to check their internals. About your suggestion: I was (still am) hoping for something that doesn't require manual adjustment, the nodes are empty most of the times, when they aren't they may be of equal length or not, and when they are I don't want them to take up any more space than needed. Furthermore, there may be many more lines in my table.

Comment: I wasn't offended:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :) That's one less concern on my list, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use 2 columns, not 1,
2. Use `rl` alignment, not `cc`,
3. Remove intercolumn gap with `@{}`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r@{}l|}
\hline
    \tikz {\node[left]{aaa};\draw[->] (0,1)--(0,-1);}&
    \tikz {\node[right]{a};\draw[->] (0,1)--(0,-1);}\\
\hline
    \tikz {\node[left]{bb};\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,1);}&
    \tikz {\node[right]{bbbb};\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,1);}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven, I guess this must be fairly standard an approach and answers my request efficiently. Unfortunately, my question wasn't precise enough and I forgot to mention a situation that I will be encountering and where your solution breaks: There may be more nodes in the picture, some even overlapping the central line. I'll see if I can adapt your solution, maybe by manually setting the bounding box. In the meantime I accept your solution since it answers the question.

Comment: Please see my answer to your other question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582656/what-column-of-a-tabular-is-a-cell-in/582815#582815

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `nicematrix` package.

Please see the code in my  answer to other question
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582815/161015

[image: x]